# How to not lose data after reloading the server?

Tags: java, database, rest

Devs! To pass the test I should get some snippets of code and return them by RESTful API requests.
I`ve done with the first part of the test and sent all snippets of code to the H2 database. In the second part of testing my program, they are reloading server by the command this::reloadServer. How I can get my data back from the database to successfully respond to RESTful requests and pass the test?

My controller:

```
@Controller
public class SnippetController {

    @Autowired
    SnippetService snippetService;
    @Autowired
    Repository repository;


    public SnippetController(SnippetService snippetService) {
        this.snippetService = snippetService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/api/code/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public Snippet getSnippet(@PathVariable int id) {
        return snippetService.getSnippet(id);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/code/{id}")
    public String showSnippet(@PathVariable int id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("snippet", snippetService.getSnippet(id));
        return "code";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/api/code/latest")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Snippet> getLatestSnippets() {
        return snippetService.getLatestSnippets();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/code/latest")
    public ModelAndView showLatestSnippets(Model model) {
        List<Snippet> sortedList = getLatestSnippets();
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("latest");
        mv.addObject("latestSnippets", sortedList);
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/api/code/new")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, String> addSnippet(@RequestBody Snippet snippet) {
        int id = snippetService.addSnippet(snippet);
        repository.save(snippet);
        return Map.of("id", String.valueOf(id));
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/code/new")
    public String showSnippetAddingForm() {
        return "create";
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8888
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:../snippetsOfCode
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false
```

[stacktrace](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PApmqe7c_bXk-U8W2m8BGPAEtU0M_M4A/view?usp=sharing)

How I should modify my controller to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, by default the H2 DB data is volatile, so data will be lost after the restart. What you can do is change H2 to use file-based storage. You don't need to change the controller, but in you can accomplish that in Spring Configuration file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:/data/demo
```

or (if using .yml):

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:file:/data/demo
```

If that is not working, maybe your DB is being re-created after the restart. You can also add that to your application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Also check if you have the below line in your persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
```

If so, remove it.

Comment: ```spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:../snippetsOfCode``` is it volotile or file-based storage?

Comment: It's file based. Could you please also share your configuration file?

Comment: And look I got it from test output:  Wrong answer in test #57  GET /api/code/1 should respond with status code 200, responded: 500. I think it's because the program trying to get snippet of code by id. But in snippetService is empty after reloading, am I right? And I should send a request with id to the database to get the right snippet?

Comment: 500 is Internal Server Error, please share stacktrace of the error.

Comment: Comment section is not he right place for sharing stacktraces, please add it to your original post message.

Comment: I added link with the file to download full stacktrace